# How to connect the server to the client and output a result in the CMD?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I'm trying to make the CMD give a signal when someone connects to the server (localhost:3000), but my code doesn't seem to work.

I have linked the CDN for the socket-client in index.html .
And also wrote some code that doesn't work.

index.html:

```
 <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"> 
 </script>
```

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var socket = require('socket.io');  
var fs = require('fs'); // required for file serving
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);    

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);
function newConnection(socket){
   console.log('new connection' + socket.id);
}
```

client.js:

```
var socket;
function setup(){
   socket = socket.io.connect('http://localhost:3000')
 }
```

I expect whenever someone joins **localhost:3000**, the **CMD** to say: "new connection: **his/her IP**".

Comment: Will you try, I think that's the problem. server.listen(3000)

Comment: I have that in my server.js (I just haven't put it up there)             
      app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', function (err) {
           if (err) {
          console.log("Failed to start web server:", err);
       } else {
          console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000');
       }
     });

Comment: okey, Have you tried the automatic script created by io?
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: I don't that's the problem because when I look at the sources in the browser console , there is a connection to the CDN

Comment: @MuhammetInan but what do I need to do to make it your way, is there something to install or do i need to change the path <script ** src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" **></script>

Comment: Understant, const { address, port } = socket.handshake.address; There is a post interested in this topic on this link. https://hk.saowen.com/a/d768f7e4d0efec7f4c248ea94799ed36bd8773b5cabf82369943d1c8153748c9

Comment: @MuhammetInan this article might work I'll try it tomorrow and see if that method works ( at least seems right to me ) .

Answer (score 0):

I left a sample code for you:

```
// Dependencies (Localhost)
const e = require('./cli.event');

// Instantiate the CLI module object.
const cli = {};

// Init Script.
cli.init = () => {
  // Send the start message to the console, in dark blue.
  console.log('\x1b[34m%s\x1b[0m', 'The CLI is running');

  // Start the interface.
  //  |_ Promt: The sign shoe the start point to the user.
  const _interface = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: '>>'
  });

  // Create an initial prompt
  _interface.prompt();

  // Handle each line of input, separately.
  _interface.on('line', str => {
    // Send to the input processor
    cli.processInput(str);
    // Re-initialize the prompt aftweward
    _interface.prompt();
  });

  // If the user stop the CLI, kill the associated process.
  _interface.on('close', () => {
    process.exit(0);
  });
};

// Command Lists
cli.uniqueInputs = [
  'man',
];
// Input processor
cli.processInput = str => {
  str = typeof str == 'string' && str.trim().length > 0 ? str : false;

  let matchFound = false;
  const counter = 0;
  // Only process the input if the user actually wrote something. Otherwise ignore it.
  if (str) {
    cli.uniqueInputs.some((input, index) => {
      if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
        matchFound = true;
        // Emit event matching the unique input, and include the full string given.
        e.emit(input, str);
      }
    });
  }

  // If no match is found, tell the user to try again.
  if (!matchFound) {
    console.log(`I don't get it, please try again.`);
  }
};
```

In a separate file, I handle the event.

```
// Dependencies (Node JS)
const event = require('events');
class _events extends event {}
const e = new _events();

const util = require('util');
const debug = util.debuglog('cli');

const os = require('os');
const v8 = require('v8');
// Dependencies (Localhost)
const _data = require('../data');
const _cliHelper = require('./cli.helper');

// Input handlers.
e.on('man', str => {
  lib.help();
});

const lib = {};
lib.help = function() {
    // Handle the event
}
```

Hopefuly, it helps you.